# Split Page Links

Tags: pages

My client wants a initial page that is split in two, with a logo of her ministry website on one side and a logo of her business on the other side. When you then click the desired logo it takes you to the corresponding website.

How can I accomplish this in WordPress? Is there even a technical name for this? All I can think of is a splash page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started.

**CSS:**

```
.home div { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
}
.home a {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="home">
    <div><a href="site.com"><img src="path-to-logo-1"></a></div>    
    <div><a href="site-two.com"><img src="path-to-logo-2"></a></div>    
</div>
```

If it's literally a single page site that only links off to two other sites, setting up WordPress for it is absolutely overkill. Download HTML5 Boilerplate or similar, stick something akin to the above into the HTML file and stuff it on the server.

Comment: Thank you for the insight here.. I will take that into consideration but I would like to know why would doing this for Wordpress be overkill?

Comment: Mainly because it's spinning up a huge framework (WordPress) and running and connecting to database when you really only need 1k of plain HTML text and a pair of images. Of course, if allowing the client to edit the content is important, there's nothing wrong with spinning up WP though there are lighter solutions (but why learn a new wheel).

Comment: Also, you could make the `path-to-logo-1` a full URL and point it at an existing WordPress site. That way, the client can still go in and change the images (though they'd need to keep the same name) and you could skip spinning up WordPress for a two images+two links web site.

Comment: Understood. I had that concept in the back of my mind. I believe I will take your suggestion as my point of attack and move on from there.. Thank you so much for your input Will.